# Firefox WebExtensions WebRequest Example not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Im trying to following with the webRequest example [given here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests#Logging_request_URLs). This simple extension should log all requests to the console, but it is not doing that. In my actual code I've included a line that changes the page's border color to red and that does work, so I know the extension code is running.

To load the extension I'm going to `about:debugging` and loading it via the `Load Temporary Add-on` button

Here is my actual code

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "description": "something something dark side",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Interceptz",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/border-48.png"
    },

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "borderify@mozilla.org",
            "strict_min_version": "45.0"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
    "*://*.mozilla.com/"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
            "js": ["intercept.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you see, I've changed the manifest from the example given on the mozilla page because copying and pasting that json without any changes causes firefox to not even load the extension

**intercept.js**

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";

function logURL(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Loading: " + requestDetails.url);
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can`t put webRequest API in the content script. You need to separate your **intercept.js**, to rename **manifest.js** to **manifest.json** and  fix permissions.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
"description": "something something dark side",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Interceptz",
"version": "1.0",
"icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
},

"applications": {
    "gecko": {
        "id": "borderify@mozilla.org",
        "strict_min_version": "45.0"
    }
},

"permissions": [
    "webRequest"
],

"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["*://*.mozilla.org/*"],
        "js": ["intercept.js"]
    }
]
}
```

**intercept.js**:

```
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
```

**background.js**:

```
function logURL(requestDetails) {
  console.log("Loading: " + requestDetails.url);
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  logURL,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}
);
```

And, of course, to add /icons/border-48.png

Comment: manifest.js was a typo, it is manifest.json. I have fixed that in my question.

Comment: Just to add to your answer, the background.js script will not log to the webpage console as seen in the picture attached. You need to open the browser console (Ctrl + Shift + J)

Comment: @francium I'm also trying to work through the same example right now and am having _exactly_ the same problem you did.  Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: @davidlav M. Onyshchuk's response works for me (just copied and pasted it as is right now). Just split the code into the content script and the background script (also include the background script line in the manifest). Then open up the browser console (NOT the regular console at the bottom of the window for editing html/website debugging) CTRL+SHIFT+J

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part from the [original tutorial of Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) is replacing this line:

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
```

with this line:

```
window.chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
```

Remove the addon, restart the brower, and add the addon again. See a working example [here](https://ops.tips/blog/extension-to-block-websites/)